# replace all no http urls to http:// in a html template string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project, which using rich text editor that some users typed link without https like this " which is broken the link. I need to find all urls without http:// in href attribute and append a http:// to them, such as " => 
".I wrote a function which can find all urls without http:// and a function find a certain patten in a string. However, every time it only changes one url, but not all urls and also return undefined. Does anyone can help? Thank you so much in advanced!

```
const text = `<h2 class="ql-align-center"><a href="wallacefund.info/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" class="ql-size-large">JUMP INTO</a><span class="ql-size-large"><a href="abc.com">abc</a>`;
// try to replace all no http:// url to http://url: 
 function getReplacedStr (target, source, wantedTarget) {
   if (source.length === 0 || target.length === 0 || target.length > source.length) return;
    for (let start = 0; start < source.length; start++) {
      if (source.charAt(start) === target.charAt(0)) {
           let end = start + target.length;
           if (end <= source.length && source.substring(start, end) === target) {
              return source.replace(target, wantedTarget);
           }
      }
    }
    return source;
 }

 // get an array contains all no http:// urls : 
 // in this case should return ["wallacefund.info/", "abc.com"]
 function getNoHttpUrls (source) {
  let regexp = /href="([^\'\"]+)/g;
  let res = [...source.matchAll(regexp)], output = '';
  const noHttpUrls = res.map(ele => {
      if (source.includes(ele[1]) && !ele[1].includes('http')) {
          return ele[1];
      }
  }).filter(e => e);
  return noHttpUrls;
 }

 const output = getNoHttpUrls(text).forEach(target => {
   return getReplacedStr(target, text, `http://${target}`);
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider parsing the text as HTML instead, and prepend all `href`s with `https` if they don't have them yet. No need for regular expressions, they make things far more complicated than needed:

```js
const text = `<h2 class="ql-align-center"><a href="wallacefund.info/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" class="ql-size-large">JUMP INTO</a><span class="ql-size-large"><a href="abc.com">abc</a>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
doc.querySelectorAll('a[href]').forEach((a) => {
  const href = a.getAttribute('href');
  if (!href.startsWith('https://')) {
    a.setAttribute('href', 'https://' + href);
  }
});

console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```